# How to merge two Excel files in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, merge

I want to merge two excel files in Python.

**File1:**

```
Number  - Date
11      - 2020-10-10
2       - 2020-10-11
30      - 2020-10-11
14      - 2020-10-11
```

**File2:**

```
Number - Type
19     - 110
23     - 110
65     - 110
2      - 134
14     - 260
31     - 260
30     - 299
11     - 299
```

**This is what I tried:**

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx') 
df2 = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx')

df1['Type'] = df1['Number'].map(df2.set_index('Number')['Type'])
```

**This is what I got:**

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

**This is what I expected:**

```
Number  - Date         -  Type
11      - 2020-10-10   -  299
2       - 2020-10-11   -  134
30      - 2020-10-11   -  299
14      - 2020-10-11   -  260
```

I checked other questions in SO but I could not find a proper answers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: @It_is_Chris no it doesnt

Comment: maybe you have duplicates in the second df probably in `Number` column . how do you want to handle them? check `df.duplicated('Number',keep=False)`

Comment: @TangerCity yes, it does answer your question if you actually read the answer.

Comment: @anky where do I need to drop that piece of code?

Answer (score 1):

Dosen't this work?

`df1.merge(df2, on='Number', how='left')`

```
   Number        Date  Type
0      11  2020-10-10   299
1       2  2020-10-11   134
2      30  2020-10-11   299
3      14  2020-10-11   260
```

Comment: based on the example you provided my output looks correct

Comment: Thats true, you are right. I didnt made a variable of it. Thank you lad. Would appreciate it if you upvoted my question.

Comment: can you please post an example that this solution doesn't work so we can help you

Comment: If the solution I provided works for you please accept the answer so this question can be closed